# The images do not work with a tutorial to follow to make my page in nextjs with i18n, can someone help me?

Tags: error-handling, public, next.js13, nextjs-image

Everything works great translate everything in nextjs13.4, tailwindcss and i18n, I'm not using typescript, but my image doesn't load anywhere despite being in the public folder.

Error that I get in the console:
GET http://localhost:3000/_next/image?url=%2Fimagentest.jpg&w=128&q=75 400 (Bad Request)

Guide: https://locize.com/blog/next-13-app-dir-i18n/

I hope you help me how to fix this code error

Answer (score 7):

this working for me:

add the const PUBLIC_FILE and add one "if" with them :

```js
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server'
import acceptLanguage from 'accept-language'
import { fallbackLng, languages } from './app/i18n/settings'

acceptLanguage.languages(languages)
const PUBLIC_FILE = /\.(.*)$/
 
export const config = {
  matcher: ['/((?!api|_next/static|_next/public|_next/image|assets|favicon.ico|sw.js).*)']
}


const cookieName = 'i18next'

export function middleware(req) { 

  let lng
  if (req.cookies.has(cookieName)) lng = acceptLanguage.get(req.cookies.get(cookieName).value)
  if (!lng) lng = acceptLanguage.get(req.headers.get('Accept-Language'))
  if (!lng) lng = fallbackLng

  //to take the files from the publisc folder
  if (    
    PUBLIC_FILE.test(req.nextUrl.pathname)
  ) {
    return
  }  

  // Redirect if lng in path is not supported
  if (
    !languages.some(loc => req.nextUrl.pathname.startsWith(`/${loc}`)) &&
    !req.nextUrl.pathname.startsWith('/_next') 
  ) {
    return NextResponse.redirect(new URL(`/${lng}${req.nextUrl.pathname}`, req.url))
  }

  if (req.headers.has('referer')) {
    const refererUrl = new URL(req.headers.get('referer'))
    const lngInReferer = languages.find((l) => refererUrl.pathname.startsWith(`/${l}`))
    const response = NextResponse.next()
    if (lngInReferer) response.cookies.set(cookieName, lngInReferer)
    return response
  }

  return NextResponse.next()
}
```

Comment: in the middleware.js

Comment: This worked for me. Thanks. That should be the solution. There are other ways to solve this issue using the "matcher" in the config. But I find it very weak.

Comment: @David Miranda.
Thanks, I was struggling to get the images as well.
I also have another issue with the next-auth since I'm using this internationalization and updated the middleware, I have a OAUTH_CALLBACK_ERROR and I'm pretty sure it's because of the changes made in the middleware.
Did you face an issue like this by any chance?